# Solve this tautology

Tags: logic, proof-writing, propositional-calculus

Hypotheses: not $q$, $p$ or not $s$, $p \rightarrow$ ($d$ and $q$), $e \rightarrow s$

Conclusion: not $e$

I have thus far, but unsure how to proceed. I am looking forward to solve it using tautologies.

$1)$ not  $q$ as premise

$2)$ $p$ or not $s$ as premise

$3)$ $p \rightarrow$ ($d$ and $q$) as premise

$4)$ $e \rightarrow s$ as premise

$5)$ $(d$ and $q)$ implies $q$ is true by simplification.

$6)$ $(d$ and $q)$ implies $q)$) and not $q$ implies not $(d$ and $q)$ by  Modus Tollens

Comment: It means "and."

Comment: Ahh, sorry, I thought "not $q$, $p$ and not $s$..." etc. was a single premise, not a list of four separate hypotheses.

Answer (score 5):

$1)$  $\lnot q$ as premise

$2)$ $p$ or $\lnot s$ as premise

$3)$ $p \rightarrow$ ($d\land q$) as premise

$4)$ $e \rightarrow s$ as premise

$5)$ $\quad p\quad$ Assumption

$6)$ $\quad d \land q\;$ (3, 5) by modus ponens

$7)$ $\quad q\;$ by simplification (6)

$8)$ $\quad q \land \lnot q\;$ (1, 8) (And-introduction)

$9)$ $\lnot p$, since assumption $p$ leads to a contradiction (5-8)

$10)$ $ \lnot s,$ from 2, 9 Disjunctive syllogism

$11)$ $\lnot e$ from 4, 10 by modus tollens.